# consume C# Rest Service from Android

Tags: c#, android

trying to do a simple communication test between my PC and phone (currently testing with emulator)
I have created a c# Rest service that works ok

URL: http://192.168.1.100:8000/REST/client
Result:

TEST STRING!

I have a Call function in my android app that looks like this:

```
public void call() 
{ 
    String URL = "http://192.168.1.100:8000/REST/client";
    EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Textbox);
    String Result = "";
    Toast.makeText(Helloworld.this, "STARTING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try{
        Result = hc.execute(request,handler);
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();   
    } catch (IOException e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();   
    } 
    txt.setText(Result);
    Toast.makeText(Helloworld.this, Result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    hc.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

}
```

i call this from a button,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Textbox);
            txt.setText("calling!", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE );
            call();
        }
        });
```

few problems, with this code as is, if i run it i dont see any Toast msgs and the textbox isnt updated. if however i remove the call() from the onclick, the textbox is updated. it seems as though the call is hanging, but even if it was, wouldnt i see the text updated anyways?

Comment: Don't run long task in UI thread. Use ex. AsyncTask

Comment: Your Toast messages are probably not showing because you're not calling `show()` on the Toast instance that comes back from `makeText()`.

Comment: Dziobas, was trying to run a test first, but when i create the actual app i will thanks

Comment: Chris - thanks, that shows the msgs and the call returns quickly, and i changed the exptions to post in the textbox and i found im getting an IO exception. new to android and java (C# guy) whats the best way to diagnose this? (using eclipse with emulator) Thanks

Comment: i just opened the web browser on my emulator, typed in the URL and the test string came up ok, so it can connect, but i still have an IO error when i run the code. im going to try and impliment Flying,s suggestion, but i dont think it will change much since the call is done the same way.

Comment: I just edited the call function, might want to try it that way. I am used to parsing the XML on my own using a DOM document, so I am unfamiliar with the response handlers. If it still doesn't work I would step through and figure out if it is the `execute()` or the `handleResponse()` that is throwing the IOException.

Comment: Thanks, the try is only doing the execute(request) statement and thats giving the IO exception (not sure how to see the stack) the service returns this exactly:
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">TEST STRING!</string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it can reach your service etc, you should be doing it with AsyncTasks and calling invalidate to make sure the updates are shown on the screen. Also, you have to call `.show()` on `makeText()`. I haven't tested this but it should be the right idea.

```
public void doBeginCall()
{
  Toast.makeText(this, "Call started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  new CallTask().execute(null);  
}

public void onCallComplete(String result)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Call complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.Textbox)).setText(result);
    invalidate();
}

class CallTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        onCallComplete(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected TaskResult doInBackground(String... params) 
    {           
        return call();
    }
}

public String call() 
{ 
    String URL = "http://192.168.1.100:8000/REST/client";
    String Result = "";
    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
    HttpResponse hr = null;
    BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try
    {
        hr = hc.execute(request);
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {   
        e.printStackTrace();   
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {   
        e.printStackTrace();   
    } 
    hc.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    return handler.handleResponse(hr);
}
```

Also, you need to have the proper permissions set up for your app. Include the following line in your manifest xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: I see you changed how the request was done, so i did it that way hc.execute(request) and i still get the IO error exception.

Comment: What method is throwing it? Do you have INTERNET permissions set up in your manifest?

Comment: Im not sure what "INTERNET" permissions are, so perhaps not because the web browser on the emulator can get to the site ok.

Comment: You need to give your app permission to access the internet, see the edit on my answer.

Comment: awesome, that did it thanks, one last thing, it shows the raw result of the page (xml) whats the best way to get the value?
    
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">TEST STRING!</string>

Comment: I have a dentist appt right now, Ill respond when I get back.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6017/discussion-between-jrich523-and-flyingstreudel)